# Getting Jenkinsfile error - command not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

What is wrong with this Jenkins file? I am new to it but I don't get what am I doing wrong

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
           dir ('/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipleline_2') { 

            }
        }     
}
}
post {
    always {
        sh 'hello2.sh'
    }
    failure {
       mail(from: "heenashree2010@gmail.com", 
       to: "qshoretechnologies@gmail.com", 
       subject: "That build passed.",
       body: "Nothing to see here")
    }
}
}
```

I am getting below error. hello2.sh exists in the directory which I have specified but I am not able to execute it. I also tried sh('hello2.sh') but it didn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
Started by user qshore
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipleline_2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipleline_2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] sh
[pipleline_2] Running shell script
+ hello2.sh
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipleline_2@tmp/durable-dbcba8b2/script.sh: line 2: hello2.sh: command not found
[Pipeline] mail
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: your indentation is broken

Comment: sh './hello2.sh'   . denotes current directory

Comment: is indentation absolutely important in jenkinsfile?

Comment: No, it's not. It is just error-prone for the author and (often) no fun to read them here.

Answer (score 1):

The script called `hello2.sh` is not found. Make sure that it is included in the repo that you're checking out.

Comment: If you mean by git repo or something, then I am not pulling from there. I wanted to just run the script from the directory. And this script is there in the directory but it is not running.

Comment: @JustCurious were you able to resolve this issue, I too am getting this error ```@tmp/durable-f390eb74/script.sh: Git: not found```

Comment: did you spell `git` with an uppercase `G`?